# Is it a bad practice to create references between projects in this way?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have Validator.sln, A.sln, B.sln, C.sln.

A, B, and C are large projects with a different primary functionality.  I want to use some of each of their logic to validate a piece of data.

So, in Validator.sln, I have a source file with:

```
public interface IValidator
{
    bool Validate(int myData);
}
```

**I want to implement this interface in A, B, and C.**  That is,

```
public Validator : IValidator
{
    bool Validate(int myData)
    {
        bool dataValidates = true;

        // Call a bunch of complicated logic

        return dataValidates;
    }
}
```

(This doesn't compile, since IValidator is undefined in this context.)

I could create an assembly reference from A to Validator, which are, for the most part, separate programs.  **Is that a bad solution?**

edit:

I could also put AValidator in Validator.sln, and then dynamically link the assemblies I want from A at run-time.  But that sort of defeats the purpose of the interface?

Comment: Can you split the common functionality and create a library from it? Then you'd just have to include the library and there's no hard reference between independent solutions.

Comment: That's what you are suppose to do.  A, B and C need to reference that Validator in order to use it.

Comment: If you have less than 100,000 lines of code between all the solutions then I would question your design – VERY large projects that have say 20 developers working on them for many years are a different case.

Comment: @IanRingrose Well over 100,000 lines, well over 20 developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No its not a bad solution.

It is in fact preferable to move common logic into it's own assembly. This saves on code duplication and maintenance costs.

You should also consider moving the logic that is common among the other three projects into the new assembly also.

We have a similar setup to what you are describing. We have a Common assembly that is shared between 3 small applications and this also has business validation (government) rules. Updating a rule across all three applications is incredibly simplified because its only in a single place.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a best solution out there, but according to the couple notions you mantioned:

- others are big projects
- probably they are not completely written by you

If this works, this is an *acceptable* solution. But is this a good solution or not, it depends on your business resources. So try to ask to the following questions:

- do you have enough time to extract without destroying anything else a part that you need to share between different projects ?
- how much risk involved in this ? How mission critical are these projects state for *your* business ?
- does it all worth an estimated effort you are going to put in ?

Good luck.

Comment: +1. You've touched on the other important side of this: is it useful/cost effective to do this.. which I would say it always is.. but others may disagree.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: we develop to gain money, so is this a *really* cost effective, in terms of IT business, or not, is up to mangers to decide. From the pure IT engineering perspective, instead, yes, it's better to refactor and put common logic into the shared assembly. But we are not in perfect world...

Comment: I agree with you. I guess I am just lucky - I am in a position where I get a lot of say in what happens with our codebase.. and luckily for us the business can survive for a few months while we are refactoring code (if we decided to do it for months!).